# Kotlin delegating to a future

Tags: java, kotlin

I am trying to learn Kotlin and delegates are both interesting and confusing. I have a situation where, in a java class I would take a constructor arg, create a Future (the ID represents a resource in another system) and stash the Future as an instange variable. Then the "getXXX" would call `Future.get()`

Here is a sample java class

```
public class Example {


     private Future<Foo> foo;

     public Example(String fooId) {

        this.foo = supplyAsync(() -> httpClient.get(fooId));
     }

     public Foo getFoo() {
      return foo.get();
     }
}
```

I am not supplying the Kotlin example because I am simply not sure how to construct it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can translate your Java code to Kotlin in a straightforward way using [custom property getters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters):

```
class Example(fooId: Int) {
    private val fooFuture = supplyAsync { httpClient.get(fooId) }

    val foo: Foo
        get() = fooFuture.get()
}
```

---

But Kotlin has a more powerful concept for generalizing property behavior -- [the property delegates](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#delegated-properties):

```
class Example {
    val foo: Foo by someDelegate
}
```

<sup>In this example, `someDelegate` is an object that defines the behavior of property `foo`.</sup>

Though `Future<V>` cannot be used as a delegate out of the box in Kotlin, you can create your own property delegates by implementing `getValue(thisRef, property)` and (for mutable properties) `setValue(thisRef, property, value)` functions, thus explicitly providing the code to be executed when a property is read (and written, if mutable).

These functions can be either member functions for your project classes or [extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extension-functions), which fits the case with `Future<V>`. Basically, to use `Future<V>` as a property delegate, you have to define the  `getValue(thisRef, value)` extension function for it, for example:

```
operator fun <V> Future<V>.getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>) = get()
```

<sup>Here, the value the delegate will provide for a property will be simply taken from the `Future::get` call, but a proper implementation should probably take care of cancellation and exceptions handling. For this purpose, you can wrap a `Future<V>` into a class that will also define the fallback values/strategies, and then use this class' objects in `by`.</sup>

Then you can use `Future<V>` objects as delegates for your properties:

```
class Example(fooId: Int) {
    val foo: Foo by supplyAsync { Thread.sleep(2000); fooId }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val e = Example(123)
    println(e.foo)
}
```

Comment: Option 2 is exactly what I am looking for because I need to repeat this everywhere. I am going to give this a spin.

Comment: An interesting question I have where I should define this extension function. I mean, it definitely doesn't belong in a data class.

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno, many Kotlin projects contain `Utils.kt` or `utils` package, and extensions are often placed there if they are used across the project. But if an extension is used locally in a single file, it looks okay to put it there and make it `private`.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answer from hotkey I propose this solution for a ReadWrite property

```
fun <V> Future<out V>.asDelegate(mayInterruptIfRunning: Boolean = false) =
object : ReadWriteProperty<Any?, V> {
    private val lock = Object()
    private var completedOrCanceled: Boolean = false
    private var mValue: V? = null
    override fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): V {
        synchronized(lock) {
            if (!completedOrCanceled) {
                mValue = get()
                completedOrCanceled = true
            }
        }
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return mValue as V

    }

    override fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: V) {
        synchronized(lock) {
            if (!completedOrCanceled) {
                cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning)
                completedOrCanceled = true
            }
            mValue = value
        }
    }
}
```

Usage could be :

```
class Example(fooId: Int) {
    var foo: Foo by supplyAsync { Thread.sleep(2000); print("job done "); fooId }.asDelegate()
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val e = Example(123)
    println(e.foo)  //"job done 123" printed after 2 sec

    val f = Example(123)
    f.foo = 456    //without waiting
    println(e.foo) //"456" printed immediately 
                   //"job done " printed after 2 sec

    val g = Example(123) //"job done " printed after 2 sec
    Thread.sleep(3000)  //wait 3 sec then
    println(e.foo) //"123" printed immediately 
    g.foo = 456
    println(e.foo) //"456" printed immediately 

}
```

note that if `mayInterruptIfRunning` is set to `true` then `"job done "` won't be printed if `f.foo = 456` is called before the 2 sec